# Getting 'UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY' even after I install updated peer

Tags: angular

Searching online, I saw some answers for this same problem for 'Ionic' and 'React', but not for my particular issue in Angular . . .

I'm trying to install `@angular/cdk/drag-drop`, but `npm install` gives error "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY" for `@angular/core` and `@angular/common`, and when I install these, I have the same problem for `rxjs` and `zone.js`. So I started with `rxjs` and `zone.js` and `installed` the latest versions for these, but even after doing so, `@angular/core` and `@angular/common` still give me "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY" messages. Below is a screen shot for `package.json` and the CLI. Many thanks in advance if anyone has any ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I kept installing dependencies, and dependencies of dependencies, until finally, even though there were still multiple warnings, everything eventually compiled. So my advice for anyone in a similar situation would be to keep installing the dependencies listed in the warnings, e.g., `npm install --save @angular/core`, `npm install --save rxjs`, etc. and keep trying to compile e.g., `ng serve`, until everything compiles.